# How to observe the Add action of DbSet<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I has two classes named `Contact` and `ContactField` as following. When the `ContactField` is added into `Contact`, I hope to assign `SortOrder` to `ContactField` automatically. Do I need to inherit DbSet and customize the `Add` method ? How to achieve it ?

```
public class Foo {
        private MyDbContext _db = new MyDbContext();

        public void HelloWorld() {
            Contact contact = ....; //< A contact from database.

            ContactField field = ....; ///< A new field 
            .... ///< assign other properties into this `field`
            field.FieldType = FieldType.Phone;

            // How to automatically update `SortOrder` 
            // when adding field into `ContactFields`
            contact.ContactFields.Add(field);

            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
}

public class Contact {
        public long ContactID { get; set; }

        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string DisplayCompany { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedTime { get; set; }

        // Original codes    
        //public virtual ICollection<ContactField> ContactFields { get; set; }
        public virtual MyList<ContactField> ContactFields { get; set; }
}

 public class ContactField {
        public long ContactFieldID { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }
        public int FieldType { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }

        [Column("ContactID")]
        public int ContactID { get; set; }
        public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
 }
```

**Edit:**
    I found what I need is to monitor the changes of `ICollection<ContactField> ContactFields`. And the `List<T>` is an implementation of `ICollection<T>`. So, I create a custom `MyList` and ask it notifies the changes of `MyList` container. I will test it works or not later.

```
public class MyList<TEntity> : List<TEntity> {
        public delegate OnAddHandler(object sender, TEntity entry);
        public event OnAddHandler OnAddEvent;

        public new void Add(TEntity entity) {
             OnAddEvent(this, entity); 
             base.Add(entity);
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DbSet has a [Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) property which is an `ObservableCollection`. You can subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event and update the sort order there.

```
public class Foo {
        private MyDbContext _db = new MyDbContext();

        public void HelloWorld() {

            _db.Contacts.Local.CollectionChanged += ContactsChanged;

            Contact contact = ....; //< A contact from database.

            ContactField field = ....; ///< A new field 
            .... ///< assign other properties into this `field`
            field.FieldType = FieldType.Phone;

            // How to automatically update `SortOrder` 
            // when adding field into `ContactFields`
            contact.ContactFields.Add(field);

            _db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void ContactsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args) {

            if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {

                // sort
            }    
        }
}
```

Comment: If the `Contact` has not been saved into `_db`, can I observe the `Add` action of `ICollection<ContactField> ContactFields` ?

Comment: Keep in mind that accessing `.Local` loads the whole table from the database into memory. Even with medium sized tables it's a huge performance impact!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively override the SaveChanges method on the DbContext, and use the local ChangeTracker property to find new entities of a particular type and set their sort order property.  Works great for setting things like last updated date in 1 place.