# Does DbContext.SaveChanges() insert new records in the order they were added to DbSet?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, entity-framework-4.3

My question assumes simple inserts into a table with no relevant relations.

```
// various unrelated operations w/context...
var one = new DbRecord();
var two = new DbRecord();
var thr = new DbRecord();
context.DbRecords.Add(one);
context.DbRecords.Add(two);
context.DbRecords.Add(thr);
// various unrelated operations w/context...
context.SaveChanges();
```

In this case, will my DbRecord entities *always* be inserted in the order I added them to the DbSet? They seem to be in my testing, but can I rely on this?

"various unrelated operations" refers to operations on different, not-related DbSets of the same context; inserts, deletes, and updated entities (POCOs, in my case)

I want them to be inserted in exact order so I can use the pk/identity field to sort by, yet I also need to take advantage of the implicit transaction that the context provides around my context.SaveChanges(). Although the other operations are not related as far as the database schema is concerned, the entries themselves are essentially log entries about the updates being performed, and their order is critical.

If the context does not guarantee inserting the records in the same order, I will have to add a datetime field to the records, and handle rolling back myself.

Comment: Why? There's no such thing as 'order of insert' in the Database itself...  Use an ORDER BY in the queries.

Comment: @Henk I'll probably end up using a datetime field and sorting on that. Trying to see if I can sort by the identity/pk field, instead.

Comment: @Henk: Of course a database has the concept of order of insertion. When you have an identity column, the value of that column is the essentially the order of insertion. You can then ORDER BY that column, and receive the records back in the order of insertion.

Comment: @AndrewBarber this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8448144-05dd-4c34-b93c-9336c3b62f6e/order-of-inserts?forum=adodotnetentityframework seems to suggest that they aren't inserted in the exact order

Comment: @SteveFord Yup; agreed! :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber also see the answer from Alex James program manager for EF in 2009 where he states they don't preserve the order http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921442/row-insertion-order-entity-framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not guaranteed according to the documentation. This means, that you cannot rely on this behavior. Basically, it comes down to the questions whether you are willing to take the risk that...

- ...your pager goes of in the middle of the night?
- ...you find, after running for a year, that 10% of these records are corrupt without any possibility to fix them retroactively?

Answering these questions is up to you. Usually, the answer should be "no".

If your testing comes up ok, this does not mean that the "unrelated actions" your were talking about don't cause any disturbance in rare situations. This is a silent bug that nobody will notice during testing.

Comment: That was exactly my concern. I built the database initially planning on adding records to that table outside the Context, but it is going to end up being much easier to use the context to help me do it. So, it looks like a datetime field is in order! +1

Comment: Of course, you can also execute SaveChanges after every log record added (and wrap everything in a transaction so it is still atomic). Or you could insert immediately using ExecuteCommand.

Comment: I can confirm from testing that elements that have been Added in a specific order were not saved in that order when I did SaveChanges(). Order cannot be guaranteed. I ended up doing a save after every insert and now it's behaving as expected (but obviously slower).

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is not inserted in the same order as added since I cannot seem to find any related information which confirms so. On the other hand, I believe this could help, at least I hope so. =)

[How to observe the Add action of DbSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543208/how-to-observe-the-add-action-of-dbsett)

Though adding a DateTime field might be easier, this approach looks interesting for what you seem to want to accomplish. It suggests you subscribe to the Add action and set the order for yourself, so that you can make sure it shall get inserted as you want it to.

Hope this helps! =)

Comment: That might be worth looking into, actually. Though a datetime field might be easier for my situation. +1 for the "don't assume, since it doesn't say so" and the idea!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it possible in your case to use an explicit transatcion? I mean I would do something like:

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope()){
  var one = new DbRecord();
  var two = new DbRecord();
  var thr = new DbRecord();
  context.DbRecords.Add(one);
  context.SaveChanges();
  context.DbRecords.Add(two);
  context.SaveChanges();
  context.DbRecords.Add(thr);
  context.SaveChanges();
  // various unrelated operations w/context...
  context.SaveChanges();
  transaction.Complete();
}
```

Comment: That would be possible to do, yes... but it would be much more complicating than simply adding a datetime field to the table. Thing is, I would need to include some of those various other operations in the specific transactions, which would mean a lot more complicated transaction code.

Comment: I don't think you would need an extra datetime field with a similar solution. Actually the point of using an explicit transaction like this is that the order of the identities are guaranteed. I don't see why would you need complicated transaction code. I don't see any difference between (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope()){ doSumeDbRelatedStuff1(); context.SaveChanges(); doSumeDbRelatedStuff2(); context.SaveChanges(); transaction.Complete(); } and the other version without an explicit transaction: doSumeDbRelatedStuff1();  doSumeDbRelatedStuff2(); context.SaveChanges();

Comment: I actually misunderstood your suggestion at first slightly. The transaction code would not actually be complicated, but the update code would be a little bit. I suppose I could just wrap the life of the Context in a transaction, and have the call to my Repository's `Save()` method commit it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only add rows, you can have the pk be incremental, in which case you CAN trust those to be in the right order. If you really want the time of the last edit, though you should use a datetime column as you said. But, altogether, sounds like you can do it all in a much more simpe and clean manner, if you want to elaborate on th real issue you are dealing with.

Comment: You are right; I'll be going the route of adding a datetime field to assure proper sorting. Although I do have incremental pk values assigned, the problem is I don't believe I can rely on EF to insert the records in the same order I told it about them.

Comment: Inceremental pk's will be assigned just right, promise. Edit: might depend on the db? What are you using for db?

Comment: I know incremental PK's will be assigned properly, based on the order the SQL INSERT statements come in, definitely. But what is not guaranteed is that Entity Framework will issue those INSERT statements in the order I called DbSet.Add();

Comment: It identifies pk as incremental and therefore the insertion order as crucial. It works. Edit: but again, its not like MS Access or something, right?

Comment: What is "it" you are referring to? EF? Do you have a link to such a claim? I've seen no such documentation that this is defined behavior, *guaranteed* to happen. Yes - in all my tests, they are inserted in order. But lacking documentation that promises this is how it's done, it would be silly to just assume.

Comment: Yes, and all you need to do is insert some data without saving changed, and look at the transaction next_pk manually. The Add command is translated to an insert command which is being executed immediately, and therefore the pk increment occurs in order.

Comment: If you really wanna be 140% sure, you can always get the item's ids after saving changed, have a nice AssureIDsIncremental(items) or something.

Comment: You are not understanding me. In my testing, it *is* being done in the right order. But **there is no guarantee it will always do that** unless I see documentation saying so.

Comment: I understand that, I just think that there is a guarantee by the definition of how EF works. It translates every single Add to an insert and runs it, and then returns. You can see it happening live using SQL profiler.

Comment: You don't understand. I have *already* tested that the commands I have run are done in that order. EF certainly does *change* the order of commands it is given in many cases. For instance, to assure referential integrity. I'm asking for **documentation** of how it works, yet you just keep telling me your guess and to test what I have already tested. If there is a guarantee, **show me it**.

Comment: @AndrewBarber EF documentation is horrible. You can't expect it to have something that specific and detailed. The best chance for imperial prove is examining the binary code.
In the worst case scenario, you can have a stored procedure to insert multiple rows, which will assure you they are inserted one after another (as you yourself will write the code).
Hey, why not just moving the PK increment logic to code-level (statically loading last PK at first), and then every item will get it's own unique PK in the order of initialization, and EF will be able to do what ever he wants to do. :)

Comment: Without documentation for it, I won't rely on it.

Comment: I considered something like in Hari's answer. In the end, though, I've decided that a datetime field is a cleaner solution for my situation.

Comment: YoryeNathan, @AndrewBarber is right, this is **never** a good idea - what happens if 2 threads access the context at the same time? (eg 2 pages on a webserver or a background timer in winforms)? This is a classic [race condition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317723). *Hoping* it will work with multiple users or a moderately complex application is a bad mistake.